# Problem with conditional rendering in React Native using falsey value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

```
<Item stackedLabel disabled>
  <Label style={{ color: 'black' }}>{someLabel}</Label>
    {
      0 &&
      <Input style={{ color: 'grey' }} value={this.props.someprop} disabled />
    }
</Item>
```

I've created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/rJQVih2w7), to demo that we can use falsey value for conditional rendering. However, the above code throwing me error

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component

However, if we replace `0` with `null`/`false` then it's working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've created a snack, to demo that we can use falsey value for
>   conditional rendering.

And the snack fails, so it's actually not the case.

Expanding on Saeed's answer, the code snippet is an equivalent of

```
<Item stackedLabel disabled>
  <Label style={{ color: 'black' }}>{someLabel}</Label>
  0
</Item>
```

React Native does not know what to do with the zero and hence prints the error.

Comment: I don't understand? Which part of the snack fails?

Comment: When you run the simulator, you are not seeing `Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.` because of `0`, which is clearly expected

Comment: @Isaac run the snack on android and you'll see an error

Comment: hmmm seems like really the case. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

That is because React sees that 0 as a string.

Simply convert it to a boolean with this trick:

!!(*anything not boolean*)

```
// this is equal to false
!!(0)
```

Comment: Not really, that's why I created the `snack` to demo that `React` handle 0 as falsey value correctly. However I can't be sure that it's NativeBase's issue

Comment: On ReactJS (not native) it handles 0 as a string. So it assumes it as a string